# VSTS WindowsMachineFileCopy can't connect to my server

Tags: azure-devops, devops

I am using VSTS WindowsMachineFileCopy task for deployment in an on-premise environment. In this on-premise environment, it just can't connect to the destination computer. I can't figure out why not... I've tried using the both the host name and also the machine IP.

What's even more weird is it is reporting "23.102.153.83:443" in the error info when I am trying to connect to a 10.* address...

Here is the exception log from the deployment:

```
2017-09-11T12:00:07.5928347Z Executing the powershell script: 
C:\agent\_work\_tasks\WindowsMachineFileCopy_731004d4-1d66-4f70-8c05-638018b22210\1.0.41\WindowsMachineFileCopy.ps1
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z ##[error]System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.102.153.83:443
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:03:56.2892363Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.3048364Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.3048364Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TaskContextHelper.GetConnection(Uri serverUri, VssCredentials credentials)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.3048364Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.Core.TaskContextHelper.GetVssConnection(ITaskContext context)
2017-09-11T12:03:56.3048364Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.GetVssConnectionCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2017-09-11T12:03:56.3048364Z    at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z ##[error]System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 23.102.153.83:443
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssHttpRetryMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__49.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.VssHttpClientBase.<SendAsync>d__46`1.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Location.Client.LocationHttpClient.<GetConnectionDataAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.Location.VssServerDataProvider.<ConnectAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException: Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Environment' because it is null.
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Management.Automation.Internal.PipelineProcessor.SynchronousExecuteEnumerate(Object input, Hashtable errorResults, Boolean enumerate)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3339268Z    at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z ##[error]System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No machine exists under environment: '10.XXXXXXXXXX' for deployment ---> System.Management.Automation.RuntimeException: No machine exists under environment: '10.XXXXXXXXXX' for deployment
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PipelineBase.Invoke(IEnumerable input)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.ConstructPipelineAndDoWork(Runspace rs, Boolean performSyncInvoke)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Worker.CreateRunspaceIfNeededAndDoWork(Runspace rsToUse, Boolean isSync)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvokeHelper[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TInput,TOutput](PSDataCollection`1 input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.CoreInvoke[TOutput](IEnumerable input, PSDataCollection`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at System.Management.Automation.PowerShell.Invoke[T](IEnumerable input, IList`1 output, PSInvocationSettings settings)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3651269Z    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Handlers.LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.VSTSPowerShellHost.Main(String[] args)
2017-09-11T12:10:29.3807269Z ##[error]LegacyVSTSPowerShellHost.exe completed with return code: -1.
```

Anyone have any ideas of what the issue might be or what I can look into?

Comment: Are you using a deployment group?

Comment: No. Deployment Groups tab is empty. Also, I have a command line task immediately before the file copy that uses ping with server address. The ping succeeds. This has me so stumped.

Comment: New information has come to light: 
I have found that this error happens with the Remote Powershell task too. So I think there is a problem with the WinRM setup on the destination. It used to be setup on the target machine, so I have a suspicion that the cert might have expired.... will check and revert with additional findings.

Answer (score 2):

**Hosted agent does not support Windows Machine File Copy task** (you can also find related issue [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3761)).

The work around is use a [private agent](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows) to deploy. Settings for Windows Machine File Copy task as below:

Machines: IP, such as `10.168.170.111`

Admin Login: `domain\username`

Password: input your password or use a variable

Destination Folder: fully path on the remote machine. Such as `C:\Users\username\Desktop\1`

Comment: Thanks Marina, this agent is locally hosted.

Comment: So you are using private agent to build? The Windows Machine File Copy can run successful by private agent if you set correctly and the remote machine is able to access. Did you build succeed with the setting as I listed above?

Comment: Thanks Marina. It is a private (on-premise) agent. I found that I am having the issue with all tasks on the target server that require Remote Powershell execution. I am suspecting that my cert has expired on the target server and so can't connect winrm. I need to re-validate my winrm setup and then try again.